# what must be specified in the fx:controller=""

Tags: javafx, controller

I used some commands for getting the controller of a fxml file. at first I used an address like this:

```
fx:controller="PersonOverviewController"
```

and the code in main class was like this

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/PersonOverview.fxml"));
AnchorPane ap = loader.load();

PersonOverviewController pc = loader.getController();
pc.setTableContent(this);
```

but it doesn't work.
in another attempt, I changed the

```
fx:controller="address.view.PersonOverviewController"
```

and this time it worked.
Why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FXMLLoader` needs the [binary name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1) of the controller class to be specified. If the package of your `PersonOverviewController` is `address.view` you therefore have to include it in the attribute value.

`FXMLLoader` basically creates the controller instance like this, if no controller factory is set:

```
String fxController = ...
Class controllerClass = getClassLoader().loadClass(fxController);
Object controller = controllerClass.newInstance();
```